# Output not as expected

Tags: c, string, pointers, for-loop, output

I am supposed to write a program to extract Web addresses starting with `www.` and ending with `.edu`. The program displays Web address contained in the input entered by the user. If the input does not contain a web address that starts with `www.` and ends with `.edu`, the program should display a message that indicates such a web address cannot be found.

```
Input: http://www.usf.edu/admission
Output: www.usf.edu
Input: https://www.facebook.com/
Output: Web address starting with www. and ending with .edu not found
```

However when my program runs, it is not displaying the correct output. I don't have any compiler errors or warnings so I'm not sure where the issue could be.

```
// This program extracts the text from the website URL
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STR_LEN 1000

void read_line(char *str, int n);
void pass_check(char *str);
void extract(char *s1, char *s2);

int main(void)
{
    char instr[STR_LEN + 1];
    char outstr[STR_LEN + 1];

    printf("Please enter a URL: ");
    read_line(instr, STR_LEN);
    extract(instr, outstr);

    puts(outstr);
    pass_check(outstr);

    return 0;
}

void extract(char *s1, char *s2) {
    char *p, *q;
    q = s2;
    for (p = s1 + 7; *p != 0; p++) {
        if (*p == '/')
            break;
        else {
            *q = *p;
            q++;
        }
    }
    *q = '\0';
    *p = '\0';
}

void read_line(char *str, int n) {
    int ch;
    int i = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (i < n) {
            *str++ = ch;
            i++;
        }
    }
    *str = '\0';
}

void pass_check(char *str) {
    const char *fref = "www";
    const char *lref = "edu";

    int len = strlen(str);
    printf("%d", len);

    char *l = &str[len - 3];
    char f[STR_LEN + 1];

    strncpy(f, str, 3);

    if ((strcmp(f, fref) == 0) && strcmp(l, lref) == 0) {
        printf("Output: ");
        puts(str);
        printf("\n");
    } else
        printf("Please only insert a .edu URL.");
}
```

Comment: If the user types a short name — `www.edu` for example — your code at `for (p = s1+ 7;` skips to the end of the string.  Even shorter, and you're reading uninitialized data (or, at least, not necessarily initialized data).  That's bad!

Comment: What input are you giving when you get the wrong output?  What output are you getting?  What should you be getting?  Why?  (For whatever it is worth, it compiled cleanly under my stringent default compilation options [**well done!**], and runs and did more or less what I'd expect it to do.  Testing — extremely casual — on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.3 with GCC 6.3.0.)  It could use some newlines at the ends of printed messages.

Comment: remove `puts(outstr);` and this `printf("%d", len);` to get the output you wanted like shown without all this length without newline outputs. Better still let us know what exactly is your expected out

Comment: If i try the sample output, http://www.usf.edu/admission, it will print www.usf.edu. However, it doesn't print out the "Output: " line and it also prints out the else statement "Please only insert a .edu URL."

Comment: @SeekAddo your solution works the first time...however if I run it a second time it goes back to the old issue for some reason.

Comment: Hmmm...leading spaces confuse it.  So do `ftp://` URLs (that's partly because of the `s1+7` issue).  Port numbers confuse it.  A `gopher://www.email.edu/` URL confuses it.  You need to think more carefully about detecting the start.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so something in my extract function should be adjusted?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i think he is thinking only for a solution, he need a generalised algorithm to detect https and others before the domain name. I don't have computer with me now in bed. i think he can use the `strspn()` or better strcspn

Comment: @DoctorCloud what inputs are you testing with and what output message is not coming. and if you don't want this `printf("Please only insert a .edu URL.");` output message when it fails then change it and put the right one there.

Comment: @SeekAddo no I'm saying even if I put an .edu url there it still says "Please only insert a .edu URL". And I'm testing it with http://www.usf.edu/admission

Comment: @DoctorCloud If you're supposed to enter `www.<name>.edu` and you enter `<name>.edu` without the `www.`, what else would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `strncpy()` does not do what you think it does: `strncpy(f, str, 3);` will not append a null byte to `f`, so `strcmp(f, fref);` will actually have undefined behavior as `f` is uninitialized beyond the first 3 bytes.

Do not use this function, learn why from these blogs:

- https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/
- https://blog.liw.fi/posts/strncpy/

Also note that your `readline()` function will run an infinite loop is the file is empty or not terminated by a newline.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LEN 1000

void read_line(char *str, size_t n);
int extract(const char *str, char *dest);

int main(void) {
    char instr[STR_LEN + 1];
    char outstr[STR_LEN + 1];

    printf("Please enter a URL: ");
    read_line(instr, sizeof(instr));
    if (extract(instr, outstr)) {
        puts(outstr);
    } else {
        printf("Web address starting with www. and ending with .edu not found\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int read_line(char *str, size size) {
    int ch;
    size_t i = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (i + 1 < size) {
            str[i++] = ch;
        }
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    return (ch == EOF && i == 0) ? EOF : i;
}

int extact(const char *str, char *dest) {
    const char *p;

    *dest = '\0';

    for (;;) {
        if ((p = strstr(str, "https://www.")) != NULL) {
            p += 8;  // skip the https:// prefix
        } else 
        if ((p = strstr(str, "http://www.")) != NULL) {
            p += 7;  // skip the http:// prefix
        } else {
            break;
        }
        // URL starts with www.
        size_t len = strcspn(p, "/ \n");  // compute length of website name
        if (len > 8 && !memcmp(p + len - 4, ".edu", 4)) {
            // copy website name, assuming dest is at least as large as str
            strncat(dest, p, len);
            return 1;
        }
        str = p + len;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Bob__: absolutely. I missed this `n` when converting the semantics from max number of characters to destination size. Thanks.